# Which journals or conferences have publication accessibility requirements?

Tags: publications

When submitting papers, I often see some elaborate requirements for submission formats, but none pertaining to [accessibility](http://www.si.edu/Content/Accessibility/Publication-Guidelines.pdf). Which journals or conferences have publication accessibility requirements? (put aside accessibility conferences)

I am mostly interested in the field of computer science > machine learning, and English-speaking venues.

Comment: I would be _very_ surprised if the answer was not "None."

Answer (score 1):

Working from the guidelines you linked: http://www.si.edu/Content/Accessibility/Publication-Guidelines.pdf, I think APA style (and probably many others) meet many of the requirements. Most of the accessibility recommendations relate to the final printing (e.g., matte paper) and not to the electronically submit manuscript. APA style recommends 12 pt Times to be used as the font with double spaced lines, 1 inch margins, and a ragged right margin, which seems to tick all the typesetting rules apart from the use of a non-recommended typeface (but as a translational typeface with high quality printing it might still be accessible).